# Default android.R.atrr. for ListView item background color

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, colors, android-resources

I know I can use the `android.R.attr.` for default values (like colors, styles, etc.)

Does anyone know which `android.R.atrr.` I need to use for the default ListView Item background color?

When I look at [the available android.R.atrr.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) I see there is `colorFocusedHighlight`, `colorLongPressedHighlight`, `colorMultiSelectHighlight` and `colorPressedHighlight`, but not one for just the item that isn't pressed/focussed/etc.

Comment: Look for `android.R.color.*` instead of attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a drawable, not a color like I mentioned in my comment.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html#list_selector_background